# Is an array in JS actually filled with empty spaces or when printed is it filled with zeros?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
mydata =[];
```

i am storing values in the array by using a numeric key that can be somewhat big

```
mydata[13525] = 1;
```

However if i only store one item as the above, when i print the array in the console it prints 13524 commas before the object, nevertheless the debugger tells me it has length  13526  and there is only one element in the array.

I am confused as i understood that JS arrays do not required every position to be filled and certainly this might consume a lot of memory on bigger numbers. Can you explain please?

Comment: How are you printing the array?

Comment: console.log(mydata);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.length` property of an array represents the highest index plus one in the array that has been assigned a value.

When you do not assign intermediate values (and thus have a sparse array), the intervening values that you have not assigned are `undefined` which is essentially the "nothing here" value in Javascript.  The console chooses to display arrays by trying to show you every value between `0` and the end of the array which is simply not a very good way to display a sparse array that is mostly empty.  That's more an artifact of a design choice in the console than anything else.  One could design a different way to display contents of an array that would handle sparse arrays differently.

Arrays are most efficient if you use consecutive indexes started from `0`.  That's what they are mostly designed for and what many implementations are optimized for since a runtime can do some optimized things if it knows there is a sequential set of values.

---

If you know you're going to mostly not be using sequences of numeric indexes starting from `0` and as such the `.length` property is of little use to you, then perhaps a plain object with arbitrary properties is a better choice.

```
var mydata = {};
mydata[13525] = 1;

console.log(mydata[13525]);   // 1
console.log(mydata.length);   // undefined - no .length property on an object
console.log(myData);          // {1: 13525}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print any non-null value in the array, instead of printing the whole array I'd use a for loop that only prints non-null values. It'd be something like this...

```
for (i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) { 
    if(mydata[i]!= null){
       console.log(mydata[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript array is bit different from others,

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
foo.length = 3;
foo; // [1, 2, 3]

foo.length = 6;
foo.push(4);
foo; // [1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined, undefined, 4]
```

While the getter of the length property simply returns the number of elements that are contained in the array, in setter, a smaller value truncates the array, larger value creates a sparse array. Guess what the setter `mydata[13525] = 1;` would do.

src: [Javascript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#array)

---

***Edit:***

to print/use only the values present, you can do

```
 mydata.forEach(function(v){console.log(v);});
```